# How to compile jsoup through Ant?

Tags: java, ant, build, compilation, jsoup

I tried to use Ant to compile the jsoup source. I can compile successfully, but cannot pass the test. Here is the process:

jsoup version: 1.6.3 ; Ant version: 1.8.2

the source of jsoup is in the directory

```
src/
```

I made a build file

```
src/build.xml
```

This file contains

```
<project name="jsoup">
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/jsoup.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="StateTrace"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <!--<java jar="build/jar/jsoup.jar" input="htmls/index.html" fork="true"/>-->
    <exec executable="java">
        <arg value="-jar"/>
        <arg value="build/jar/jsoup.jar"/>
        <arg value="htmls/index.html"/>
    </exec>
</target>
</project>
```

Note: 
1. StateTrace.java is my own test program (as below); 2. htmls/index.html is the input to StateTrace.java.

```
String html;   // contains the content in htmls/index.html
...
try{
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
}catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Then I compile and run it with Ant:

```
> ant compile
> ant jar
> ant run
```

After this, I got err like:

```
run:
 [exec] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at StateTrace.main(Unknown Source)
 [exec] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 [exec]     at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
 [exec]     at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
 [exec]     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.loadEntities(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     ... 9 more
 [exec] Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

However, if I manually compiled all the java source, like

```
javac src/org/jsoup/*.java src/org/jsoup/parser/*.java src/org/jsoup/examples/*.java src/org/jsoup/nodes/*.java src/org/jsoup/safety/*.java src/org/jsoup/select/*.java src/org/jsoup/helper/*.java
```

I could compile successfully and pass my test.

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid your question does not contain enough information in its current form. build.xml does not work with the recent versions of ant (e.g. 1.8.2) and what is in htmls/index.html? Are you using the latest version of the jsoup source code (1.6.3)? StateTrace is not part of jsoup either - is this your own code? I'm happy to look at your problem, but I need enough information to reproduce it.

Comment: @richj Thank you for your questions. You're right. Let me provide more info. Please see the updated version of question.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Please add the line of code in StateTrace.main(...) that calls Jsoup.parse(...). I'm particularly interested in the values that are sent to the html and [optional] baseUri parameters. Thanks.

Comment: @richj I updated the question. The invocation of Jsoup library is very simple. I also tried Jsoup.connect(url).get(). But the same error.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. Running from an IDE everything is fine, executing the jar from ant fails with the same stacktrace. The only difference that I have found between the two so far is that the jar contains six package-info.class files - and the usual jar file meta-inf file as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This build.xml works with ant 1.8.2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="jsoup">
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/jsoup.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <!--<java jar="build/jar/jsoup.jar" input="htmls/index.html" fork="true"/>-->
        <exec executable="java">
            <arg value="-jar"/>
            <arg value="build/jar/jsoup.jar"/>
            <arg value="htmls/index.html"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

... waiting for more information ...
... until it turns up, my guess would be that there is no file at htmls/index.html

Comment: I just used the build.xml you provided (I replaced "htmls/index.html" to a real url). But I got the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the fundamental cause of this error. But I did make it work finally.

It seems the classes files need to be kept in the same directories of source files. So a build.xml is like this:

```
<project>
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="src" includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/jsoupIns.jar" basedir="src">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <!--<java jar="build/jar/jsoup.jar"  destdir="build/classes" input="htmls/index.html" fork="true"/>-->
    <exec executable="java">
        <arg value="-jar"/>
        <arg value="build/jar/jsoupIns.jar"/>
        <arg value="http://www.google.com"/>
    </exec>
</target>
</project>
```

If you know any clue of the deeper causes of this problem, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The jar file needs to contain the files entities-base.properties and entities-full.properties in the jar directory org/jsoup/nodes. Adding a fileset to the ant jar task to include these files was sufficient.

```
<target name="local.all.build" >

   <echo message="Building ${local.app.jar.name}" />
   <mkdir dir="${top.dirs.class}"/>
   <mkdir dir="${top.dirs.jar}"/>

   <javac srcdir            = "${local.dirs.source}"
          destdir           = "${top.dirs.class}"
          debug             = "true"
          includeantruntime = "false" >
      <classpath refid="top.app.classpath"/>
      <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
   </javac>

   <jar jarfile   = "${top.dirs.jar}/${local.app.jar.name}"
        basedir   = "${top.dirs.class}" >
      <fileset dir      = "${top.dirs.source}"
               includes = "**/*.properties" />
   </jar>

</target>
```